# How to convert multiple html tables into a pandas dataframe by using a customized function?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to convert multiple html tables to a pandas dataframe,
For this task I've defined a function to return all these html tables as a pandas dataframe,

However the function returns a null list `[]` when the idea is that it returns a pandas dataframe.

Here's what I've tried so far:

### Getting all the needed links as a list

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import html5lib
import pandas as pd
import string

###  defining a list for all the needed links ###

first_url='https://www.salario.com.br/tabela-salarial/?cargos='
second_url='#listaSalarial'
allTheLetters = string.ascii_uppercase

links = []

for letter in allTheLetters:
   links.append(first_url+letter+second_url)
```

### defining a function

```
### defining function to parse html objects ###

def getUrlTables(links):
  for link in links:

      # requesting link, parsing and finding tag:table #
      page = requests.get(link)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
      tab_div = soup.find_all('table', {'class':'listas'})

  # writing html files into directory #
  with open('listas_salariales.html', "w") as file:
    file.write(str(tab_div))
    file.close
  
  # reading html file as a pandas dataframe #
  tables=pd.read_html('listas_salariales.html')
  return tables
```

### Testing output

```
getUrlTables(links)

[]
```

Am I missing something in `getUrlTables()`?

Is there an easier way to accomplish this task?

Comment: 1. you are looping through you links and saving table in last link to a file (all others are discarded). 2.  this would not be a well formed HTML document (no html or body elements) - how does your html file look as text and how does it look when you open it in a browser?

Comment: @Rob Raymond, indeed, maybe an extra line that could iterate these htmls; it looks the same, but not like the table I want, in either one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will fetch the HTML from all the links, parse them to extract the table data and construct a large combined dataframe (*I have not stored the intermediate dataframes to the disk, which might be needed if the size of the tables become too large*):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import html5lib
import pandas as pd
import string

###  defining a list for all the needed links ###

first_url='https://www.salario.com.br/tabela-salarial/?cargos='
second_url='#listaSalarial'
allTheLetters = string.ascii_uppercase

links = []

for letter in allTheLetters:
    links.append(first_url+letter+second_url)

### defining function to parse html objects ###

def getUrlTables(links, master_df):
    for link in links:
        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')   # using the lxml parser
        try:
            table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'listas'})

            # finding table headers
            heads = table.find('thead').find('tr').find_all('th')
            colnames = [hdr.text for hdr in heads]
            #print(colnames)
            
            # Now extracting the values
            data = {k:[] for k in colnames}
            rows = table.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
            for rw in rows:
                for col in colnames:
                    cell = rw.find('td', attrs={'data-label':'{}'.format(col)})
                    data[col].append(cell.text)

            # Constructing a pandas dataframe using the data just parsed
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
            master_df = pd.concat([master_df, df], ignore_index=True)
        except AttributeError as e:
            print('No data from the link: {}'.format(link))
    return master_df


master_df = pd.DataFrame()
master_df = getUrlTables(links, master_df)
print(master_df)
```

The output from the above code is as follows:

```
         CBO                    Cargo  ... Teto Salarial Salário Hora
0     612510            Abacaxicultor  ...      2.116,16         6,86
1     263105                    Abade  ...      5.031,47        17,25
2     263105                 Abadessa  ...      5.031,47        17,25
3     622020  Abanador na Agricultura  ...      2.075,81         6,27
4     862120  Abastecedor de Caldeira  ...      3.793,98        11,65
...      ...                      ...  ...           ...          ...
9345  263110      Zenji (missionário)  ...      3.888,52        12,65
9346  723235                 Zincador  ...      2.583,20         7,78
9347  203010               Zoologista  ...      4.615,45        14,21
9348  203010                  Zoólogo  ...      4.615,45        14,21
9349  223310              Zootecnista  ...      5.369,59        16,50

[9350 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Please verify if all the data is correctly captured from the website!

Comment: use `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` just after `import pandas as pd` to display all the columns. To reset this behaviour, use `pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')`.